# How can I use crosstalk to produce a client-side summary table and graphics with filters?

Tags: javascript, html, r, r-markdown, crosstalk

The `crosstalk` package mentions that it is used for brushing and filtering in the description.  There is however, `summary widget`, which allows for the calculation of a single summary statistic.

Since I am able to calculate a single summary statistic based on filtered data, why not expand and produce a table of summary statistics and visualizations based on this summary to go with?

So far, I have managed to produce a table in my html output, with `summarywidget`s in multiple cells of the table.  And a copy button that allows a viewer to select and copy the data from the table, but that's it.

My method thus far:

**1.** Set up data and totals for all combinations with group_by() and  create a shareddata element with `crosstalk`.

```
---
title: "Stack Question"
output: html_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(stringr)
#library(instR)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyr)
library(crosstalk)

ourdata<-data.frame(Rock=c(2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                    Paper=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                    Team=c("Green","Blue","Green","Blue","Green","Blue","Green","Blue"),
Skill=c("High", "High","High","High","Low","Low","Low","Low"),
Position=c("Forward","Forward","Center","Center","Forward","Forward","Center","Center"))

##tables of all combinations and the associated totals
ourdata2<-ourdata%>%
  group_by(Team,Skill,Position)%>%
  summarize(Rock_Total=sum(Rock),
            Paper_Total=sum(Paper))

##creating crosstalk shareddata element
shared_ours<-SharedData$new(ourdata2)
```

**2.** Contruct filters for each categorical variable

```
## filters
bscols(widths=c(6,NA,NA),
       list(filter_select('Team','Team',shared_ours,~Team,multiple=FALSE)),
       list(filter_select('Skill','Skill',shared_ours,~Skill,multiple=FALSE)),
       list(filter_select('Position','Position',shared_ours,~Position,multiple=FALSE))
              
       )
```

**3.** Use manually-written html code to produce a table element with the id of "example", filling in each cell with a `summarywidget`.

````
<table id="example" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Rock Total</th>
<th>Paper Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

```{r, echo=FALSE, collapse=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}


summarywidget::summarywidget(shared_ours,statistic = 'sum',column = 'Rock_Total')

```
</td>

<td>

```{r, echo=FALSE, collapse=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

summarywidget::summarywidget(shared_ours,statistic = 'sum',column = 'Paper_Total')


```


</td>
</tr>
</table>
````

**4.** Use javascript version of `datatable` to display the table.

````
```{js}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();


```
````

**5.**  Use a script to generate a copy button for the table (since I didn't manage to successfully set up the button extension for `datatable`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectElementContents(el) {
        let body = document.body, range, sel;
        if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
            range = document.createRange();
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            try {
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            } catch (e) {
                range.selectNode(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        } else if (body.createTextRange) {
            range = body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.select();
        }
        document.execCommand("Copy");}

</script>



<button type="button" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('example') 
);">Copy Table</button>
<br>
<br>
```

As it stands, I'm not quite where I want to be.  Yes, there is a copyable table that contains summary statistics that result from `crosstalk` filtering, but the table lacks in style, and was clunky and manual to produce. So far, I've got no clue how to get visuals with `plotly` (or similar) that respond the the results in this summary table.  I have thought of a few ways that this might be solved, and hope that someone can tell me if they're possible and how to implement them!

Possible solutions:

- Can I make a dataframe that contains `summarywidgets`?  This way, I could refer to this new dataframe in producing tables with `DT` and graphics with `plotly` and I'd be happily back into my  default r coding form.
- If not, can I work around this by containing `summarywidgets` in the manually-produced html table (like above)? Then, is there a way to refer to this manually-created html table as the data source for `plotly` or `DT`'s data argument?
  (Side question: if this is the way to go, is there a less-manual way to get widgets made and into an html table?)
- Has a solution for strictly client-side summary with filters come into being that makes the ultimate goal here attainable?

Thank you in advance for your help!